# i want to change the color when the mouse is over and return it when it leave (html)?

Tags: html, css

what i have to write in `onmouseover` to change the background color of `<td>` in the `topic_name` class:

```
<td dir="rtl" class="topic_name" onmouseOver=""><\td>
```

this is `topic_name` class:

```
.topic_name {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #627AAD;
    padding: 0cm;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 255px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;cursor=hand;
}
```

Comment: What is `cursor: pointer;cursor=hand;`? And have you tried searching the Web?

Comment: cursor=hand; should be cursor:hand;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CSS [hover](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_hover.asp) selector

```
.topic_name:hover{
   background-color:yellow;
 }
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/TpZVP/)

Comment: i want to change the entire `td` background color

Comment: @Buffon: How does this not change the entire `td` background color?

Comment: @xmarcos : but how can i make it available to IE6 users

Comment: This might solve the IE6 problem http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/css-ie-hover1.shtml

Comment: Or if you want to use JavaScript, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
onMouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#000';" onMouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#627AAD';
```

You can always use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and make your life easier ;)